# Convert JSON to CSV using SimpleExcel

Tags: php, json, csv

I am trying to convert a JSON file to CSV using SimpleExcel: https://github.com/faisalman/simple-excel-php

Following the documentation, I created the following PHP file:

```
    <?

use SimpleExcel\SimpleExcel;

echo "test";

$excel = new SimpleExcel('JSON');
$excel->parser->loadFile('test.json');

echo $excel->parser->getCell(1, 1);

$excel->convertTo('CSV');
$excel->writer->addRow(array('add', 'another', 'row'));
$excel->writer->saveFile('example');

?>
```

Where test.json is local. For some reason this doesn't work. I was hoping it could create a CSV locally but instead it gives an error:

test
Fatal error: Class 'SimpleExcel\SimpleExcel' not found in test.php on line 7

Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Most of their examples focus on converting CSV to XML.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry! Copy and paste issue. I am using ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not autoloading classes, you still need to include/require_once the SimpleExcel source files.

Comment: I've forked and continue develop SimpleExcel https://github.com/sergeyklay/simple-excel-php. Now SimpleExcel uses Composer autoload